# Is this memory leak in VertexDelete a bug?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, memory

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

Test the below function:

```
Func[g_] := 
Module[{G, vl, vdG},    
G = g;    
While[VertexCount[G] != 0,  
vl = VertexList[G];  
vdG = Map[VertexDegree[G, #] &, vl];     
vl = Extract[vl, Position[vdG, Max[vdG]]];     
G = VertexDelete[G, vl[[1]]];
];
Return[True];    
]
```

with

```
While[g = RandomGraph[
   BernoulliGraphDistribution[ RandomInteger[{50, 100}], 
    RandomReal[]]]; Func[g]; True]
```

The same if `Module[{G=g,...`

Good if `G = Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g]];`

Is there any method to copy a graph efficiently?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I tried to edit the code to make a little more sense.  Please role back either Micheal or ZYX if you don't approve.

Comment: Confirmed. Please report bugs to [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/).

Comment: @Szabolcs 11.2 is out ?!

Comment: @gwr http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/09/14/its-another-impressive-release-launching-version-11-2-today/

Answer (score 10):

I can reproduce the problem.  A more minimal example is

```
Dynamic@N[a/1024^2]

While[True,
 VertexDelete[RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[50, 0.5]], 1];
 a = MemoryInUse[];
]
```

Please report this to Wolfram Support.